Open source app goes to first item in BottomNavigationDrawer when you press a button on xbox controller
Check out my open source app - https://github.com/Rich43/GamepadMacroPlus
When you press a button on the xbox controller, it always goes to the first item in the bottom navigation drawer. I don't want this to happen because one of the tabs are for testing xbox controllers.
While your at it, can you give me advice on how to properly read from an XBox controller in a Java Android app?
Tried subclassing the BottomNavigationDrawer but it did not help.
Expecting it to stay on same tab when you press buttons on the xbox controller (paired with bluetooth).
